# How to prevent crashes during quick tapping on bottomNavigationView android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

In my app I have main activity with container and bottomNavigationView with 5 items. At container I can show fragments with information. I can change fragment by clicking on buttons which are placed on bottomnavigation view. I noticed the problem:
when I click on items very quickly I receive or app crashes because my view is looking for view-elements or another problem is that my parent activity toolbar show wrong title/subtitle. For example I can click  on item 1 and then quickly tap on item 2 and if I continue tapping toooo quickly I can see that toolbar show content which demand to wrong fragment. I thought that maybe checking fragment visibility will solve this problem but it didn't help me. I tried also to check if fragment is visible from `onCreateView` at fragment and it didn't help me too. Here is the code of bottomNavigationView listener:

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.item_id_1-> {
                supportActionBar!!.show()
                [....]
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, jobList).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                textSetter("Item_0", resources.getString(R.string.all_jobs) + " " + sp!!.getString("all_jobs", ""))
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.item_id_2-> {
               bottom_navigation_t.menu.findItem(R.id.received_mess).title.chunked(1)
                disableShowHideAnimation(supportActionBar!!)
                supportActionBar!!.show()
               [.....]

      textSetter(resources.getString(R.string.title_activity_message_center), resources.getString(R.string.received))
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, messageList).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.item_id_3-> {

                disableShowHideAnimation(supportActionBar!!)
                supportActionBar!!.hide()
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, PersonalPage()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.item_id_4-> {

                disableShowHideAnimation(supportActionBar!!)
                supportActionBar!!.show()
                [....]
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, notepadScr).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.item_id_5-> {

                disableShowHideAnimation(supportActionBar!!)
                supportActionBar!!.hide()
                textSetter(resources.getString(R.string.more_bottom_nav), "")
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, MoreScreenK()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

maybe problem at the `setter` function, I don't know.

Comment: Can you paste the logcat ?

Comment: log cat of what? I don't have fatal crashes because I added null checking, the main problem is that I see wrong data at toolbar :)

Comment: @AshishKumar, I also see some problem with inflating menu resources for toolbar

Comment: That is why, let the app crash and paste the logs so that we can find the actual issue

Comment: but it doesn't crash, I only see wrong data after fragment replacement, maybe we can solve it?

Comment: @Andrew I am having the same problem did you manage to resolve the issue please help

Comment: @MRamzan, yes I resolved it. you have to add toolbars to each fragment and hide activity toolbar and quick tapping will be good :)

Comment: Thanks! for a really quick response

Comment: I am Doing the same but the testing teams do rapid switching and fragments are not switched correctly, looks like they are left far behind clicks.

Comment: for example it is one item selection `R.id.home_screen -> {
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, PersonalPage()).commit()
                bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.home_screen).title.chunked(1)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }` maybe it will help you

Comment: I will try it  Thanks A Lot :)